# ¿Cómo delimitar un rango específico de horas entre dos timepicker?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy trabajando en la selección de un rango de horas con *timepicker* de jQuery. Simplemente se debe seleccionar una hora inicial y una hora final, cuyo rango entre ambas no sobrepase las dos horas. La idea es que al seleccionar la hora inicial, el *timepicker* de la hora final sólo despliegue mínimo la hora inicial seleccionada y máximo dos horas posteriores a la hora inicial seleccionada; no debería mostrar horas anteriores o posteriores a ese rango. Traté de atribuir el valor del la etiqueta *input* llamada "inicial" a las propiedades *"minTime"* y *"maxTime"* del *timepicker* correspondiente a "final", pero no está resultando.

¿Alguna idea de cómo se podría lograr lo propuesto anteriormente? De antemano, gracias.

**VISTA:**

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label>HORA INICIAL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inicial" id="inicial" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label>HORA FINAL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="final" id="final" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT (jQuery):**

```
$(function(){

  $('#inicial').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00',
    startTime: '12:00',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    zindex: 9999999
  });

  $('#final').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: $('#inicial').val(),
    maxTime: $('#inicial').val() + 2,
    startTime: $('#inicial').val(),
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    zindex: 9999999
  });

});
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/xztqyh6u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner los valores del segundo `timepicker` una vez has seleccionado los del primero.

Por lo que he visto [en su documentación](https://timepicker.co/options/) tienen la opción de realizar acciones al cambiar el valor. Poniendo en el evento `change` que ponga como valor mínimo la hora seleccionado en el primer selector y sumándole 2 horas al valor como máximo debería funcionar:

```js
$(function(){

  $('#inicial').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00',
    startTime: '12:00',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    zindex: 9999999,
    change: function(time){

      $('#final').val('');

      $('#final').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        interval: 30,
        dynamic: true,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true,
        zindex: 9999999
      });

      var inicialTime = time.getTime();
      var minTime = new Date(time.getTime() + (.5*60*60*1000));
      var maxTime = new Date(time.getTime() + (2*60*60*1000));
      $('#final').timepicker('option','minTime', minTime);
      $('#final').timepicker('option','maxTime', maxTime);
  
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-timepicker-container{position:absolute;overflow:hidden;box-sizing:border-box}.ui-timepicker,.ui-timepicker-viewport{box-sizing:content-box;height:205px;display:block;margin:0}.ui-timepicker{list-style:none;padding:0 1px;text-align:center}.ui-timepicker-viewport{padding:0;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden}.ui-timepicker-standard{font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid #AAA;color:#222;margin:0;padding:2px}.ui-timepicker-standard a{border:1px solid transparent;color:#222;display:block;padding:.2em .4em;text-decoration:none}.ui-timepicker-standard .ui-state-hover{background-color:#DADADA;border:1px solid #999;font-weight:400;color:#212121}.ui-timepicker-standard .ui-menu-item{margin:0;padding:0}.ui-timepicker-corners,.ui-timepicker-corners .ui-corner-all{-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}.ui-timepicker-hidden{display:none}.ui-timepicker-no-scrollbar .ui-timepicker{border:none}/*# sourceMappingURL=jquery.timepicker.min.css.map */
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label>HORA INICIAL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inicial" id="inicial" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label>HORA FINAL:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="final" id="final" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A ver si con esto puedes seguir avanzando

Comment: Sí leí sobre el evento "change", pero yo lo había encontrado con el nombre "onChange", lo cual por estar manejando el nombre erróneo del evento no me producía ningún resultado.  Me ha funcionado tu respuesta, llevaba tiempo atorada en ese punto. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado, de nada! 